# Rails: How to check if content_for provided or not?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

In my RoR 4.2 application, all pages provide a **:title**, used in the HTML header `<TITLE>` tag.
And dynamic pages also provide a **:page_heading** content, which is displayed in my application header layout.

To keep a consistent look, I want the title to be also displayed in the application header layout for static pages, i.e when **:page_heading** is not provided.

Here is the beginning code of a show view:

```
<% provide(:title, 'Managing business rules') %>
<% content_for :page_heading do %>
<h1>Business Rule: <%= @business_rule.name %></h1>
<% end %>
----
```

Here is the code embedded in the _header.html.erb application layout:

```
<h1> <%= yield(:page_heading.empty? ? :title : :page_heading) %> </h1>
```

So, for static pages :title is displayed in IceWeasel title bar, and in the application header as well, which is correct.

But, for dynamic pages :title is displayed in IceWeasel title bar, and also in the application header, where :page_heading is expected.

The condition on the symbol **:page_heading.empty?** does not work.

How can I specify this condition correctly and have the expected symbol provided to the yield function?

Thanks.

Comment: `Symbol`s *always* evaluate to themselves. `:page_heading` will *always* evaluate to `:page_heading`, `:page_heading` is obviously not empty (it has the value `:page_heading`). Therefore, there really is no sensible way for `:page_heading.empty?` to ever be `true`. The question asking whether or not a `Symbol` is empty doesn't even make sense. A `Symbol` is always itself and therefore never empty. It's like asking the number `42` whether it is empty. No, of course, it isn't empty, it's `42`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer by @Beerlington is right, I'll just add another option to DRY the code a bit.

```
<h1>
  <%= yield(content_for?(:page_heading)? :page_heading : :title) %>
</h1>
```

Comment: yeah! Looks like someone already edited my answer with this too.

Comment: if a I yield an empty content, would it be falsey? , meaning would something like this work `yield(:page_heading) || yield(:title)`

Comment: I finally implemented this solutions, and it works fine. Thanks !

Answer (score 8):

You can check for the content by using [content_for?](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/CaptureHelper.html#method-i-content_for-3F)

```
<h1>
  <% if content_for? :page_heading %>
    <%= yield :page_heading %>
  <% else %>
    <%= yield :title %>
  <% end %>
</h1>
```

or in short:

```
<h1><%= yield(content_for?(:page_heading) ? :page_heading : :title) %></h1>
```